# Applying backdrop filter to inner SVG elements

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

I am trying to implement a design in an Angular/Ionic app. It includes a card-like element, which is a slightly transparent complex shape, that blurs the background behind it. The problem I face is that `backdrop-filter` property either doesn't work at all, or blurs the entire SVG container, as shown:

[image: Blurred]

The transparent section is made out of 4 SVGs I made in SVGator, each containing a single ellipse or rectangle element.
I'm not sure if I should post the entire template, since it includes Angular bindings in it and would be useless if copy/pasted, but here is the template structure and the last SVG, which is hardcoded:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg>
    <ellipse />
  </svg>
  <svg>
    <rect />
  </svg>
  <svg>
    <rect />
  </svg>
  <svg>
    <ellipse />
  </svg>
</div>
```

```
<svg id="bottom_circle" width="125" height="50" viewBox="0 0 125 50">
    <ellipse
      rx="71.27852"
      ry="79.973999"
      transform="matrix(.876842 0 0 0.781504 62.5-12.5)"
      fill="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)"
    />
  </svg>
```

Do you have any ideas on how to contain the filter within the visible part of the SVGs?

Comment: How are you applying `backdrop-filter`?

Comment: @Ouroborus I tried both ways - on the svg container itself - results in what's seen in the image, and on the child - doesn't work at all.

Comment: MDN says [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) affects everything under/behind the target. So the solution would be to ensure the SVGs are drawn under the things you don't want blurred. One way this might be achieved is with [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Comment: The only thing behind the svg is the background, though.